# Is there a vectorized method for replacing factor levels in tidyverse

Tags: r, function, refactoring, vectorization, forcats

I want to be able to efficiently recode the factor levels of a large number of variables (columns) of a data frame by replacing one of the levels with the name of the variable (column).

```
Health <- tibble(Anemia = c("yes", "no", "no"), 
BloodPressure = c("no", "yes", "no"),
Asthma = c("no", "no", "yes"))
```

And I want to the output to look like this

```
Health2 <- tibble(Anemia = c("Anemia", "no", "no"), 
BloodPressure = c("no", "BloodPressure", "no"), 
Asthmal = c("no", "no", "Asthma"))
```

I want this output without changing each level by hand because I have a database with 100 or so variables that I have to recode.  I tried to create a function to do this

```
Med_rename <- function(x) {
  levels = c(no = "no", names(x) ="yes")
  fct_recode(x, !!!levels)
}

Med_rename2 <- function(x) {
  y = names(x)
  levels = c(no = "no", y ="yes")
  fct_recode(x, !!!levels)
}
```

but the output of either of these attempts or others using vectorized attempts to replace the levels does not replace "yes" with variable (column) name.  Is there another vectorized way to replace the "yes" with a column name and apply to large set of variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cur_column()` in `dplyr` to use the name of the column to replace.

```
library(dplyr)

Health %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., . == 'yes', cur_column())))

#  Anemia BloodPressure Asthma
#  <chr>  <chr>         <chr> 
#1 Anemia no            no    
#2 no     BloodPressure no    
#3 no     no            Asthma
```

In base R, with `lapply` :

```
Health[] <- lapply(names(Health), function(x) 
                   replace(Health[[x]], Health[[x]] == 'yes', x))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  The ```lapply``` solution works without error.  Unfortunately, the ```dplyr``` solution threw the following error: ```Error in Health(.) : could not find function "Health"```

Comment: Are you sure you are copying the same code as in my answer? I don't get any such error using the data in your post.

Comment: Yes, I copied the code exactly.  I restarted my R project and it worked after re-creating the original tibble.  The error appeared to be related to missing value in my raw data set.  Once I removed it, There were no more errors.  Thank you!